# How to listen to hardware buttons in Android Java as a Native Flutter as I tried onKeyDown() but it doesn't work?

Tags: java, android, flutter

**MainActivity.java**

```
package com.example.trial;
import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import io.flutter.embedding.android.FlutterActivity;
import io.flutter.embedding.engine.FlutterEngine;
import io.flutter.plugin.common.MethodChannel;

import android.view.KeyEvent;
import android.view.WindowManager;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.content.DialogInterface;


public class MainActivity extends FlutterActivity {
  private static final String CHANNEL = "For sending hello";

  @Override
  public void configureFlutterEngine(@NonNull FlutterEngine flutterEngine) {
  super.configureFlutterEngine(flutterEngine);
    new MethodChannel(flutterEngine.getDartExecutor().getBinaryMessenger(), CHANNEL)
        .setMethodCallHandler(
          (call, result) -> {
              System.out.println("Hellooo from JAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAVAAAAAAAAAAAAA");
            // Note: this method is invoked on the main thread.
             @Override
             boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
                     if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
                       return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
                     }
                     switch (keyCode) {
                       case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_MEDIA_PLAY:
                               yourMediaController.dispatchMediaButtonEvent(event);
                               return true;
                     }
                     return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
             }
            
  }
}
```

So the issue is I want to read hardware buttons in flutter app, I have tried using hardware_buttons plugin but it doesn't quite work in foreground. So I decided to code in native language and now I am unable to use the keyDown() as it is giving me the below error

```
D:\Projects\trial\android\app\src\main\java\com\example\trial\MainActivity.java:28: error: ';' expected
            boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
                             ^
D:\Projects\trial\android\app\src\main\java\com\example\trial\MainActivity.java:28: error: ';' expected
            boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
                                                   ^
D:\Projects\trial\android\app\src\main\java\com\example\trial\MainActivity.java:28: error: not a statement
            boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
                                                    ^
D:\Projects\trial\android\app\src\main\java\com\example\trial\MainActivity.java:28: error: ';' expected
            boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
                                                         ^
4 errors

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
> Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 2s
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
```

Sorry if this is a rookie question, If this is a wrong way please suggest me some other way in order to listen to the buttons in foreground/background itself.

Thank You in advance!